# scale9grid functioning on child movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, scaling, movieclip

I'm working on a UI project that requires that the automatic resizing buttons (based on label length) have a focus indicator graphic for keyboard or controller focus. This graphic must obviously scale with the parent as you would imagine.

This causes a problem; the parent clip is 9sliced, and that slicing doesn't fall through to the child Sprites/MovieClips of this clip. The focus indicator needs to be an accessible property because it has to be capable of being turned on or off.

Currently the only solution I can image is an extremely programmatical reimplementation of scale9Grid where I split the focus indicator into 9 and alter the 9 parts' properties any time the parent width/height/scaleX/scaleY is changed. This would also mean turning all 9 parts on and off when that button is focused

Is there any better way than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you create some wrapper class `AppButton` (or may be you already have one since you have some resizing by label functionality) with method `setSkin(skin:MovieClip)` (where skin is your `MovieClip` from the library) and overridden setters for `width` and `height`, so you can implement here skin resizing logic in method `arrange()` that called each time width or height are changed.

Skin can be complex - with other movie clips in children (focus border in your case), so don't use scale9Grid for the hole skin, but *set sizes directly to the children with set scale9grid them as well*, so your `arrange` method can be like that:

```
private function arrange():void
{
    var child:DisplayObject;
    for(var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
    {
        child = getChildAt(i);
        child.width = width;
        child.height = height;
    }
}
```

It's also worth to make one skin format for button skins in project, so you can use one wrapper for all buttons.

Later you can add more features to this `AppButton` - switching view states on mouse events, setting text label, animating skins and so.

This approach work for me for many years, we have base `ToggleButton` and `LabelButton extends ToggleButton` classes, and extends them in every project with custom skin parsing and arranging.

Comment: This actually sounds like a very clever way to handle buttons and components in general. I will certainly be implementing this in the future. At the moment I'm stuck using a terrible API, but I'm pushing for the chance to rewrite it.